# Add jQuery colorbox plugin to a dynamically created element

Tags: jquery, anchor, colorbox

The usual way to assign color box functionality on a link is like this:

```
$("a.colorbox").colorbox({ transition: "elastic" });
```

Newly added items are not bound in this way though.

How can I add colorbox to dynamically created

```
<a class="colorbox"></a>
```

elements too?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [method described here](http://groups.google.com/group/colorbox/browse_thread/thread/3f5c6de91371a962/38dae71332c3b7c3?lnk=gst&q=bind+live#38dae71332c3b7c3) is to live-bind to the `click` event on the elements you're interested in (such as `.colorbox` in this instance) and call the colorbox library function in the handler:

```
$('.colorbox').live('click', function() {
  $.colorbox({href:$(this).attr('href'), open:true});
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 18):

You could also try this:

```
$('.colorbox').live('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).colorbox({open:true});
});
```

I think it's a little cleaner then using the `fn` command.

Comment: Thank you simonthetwit, this worked for me - using $(this) was able to provide colorbox with the image information contained in the link, whereas sunburst's solution merely opened up an unstyled and empty colorbox.

Answer (score 12):

As **live** is depreciated, you should use **on**

```
$('body').on('click', '.colorbox', function() {
    $('.colorbox').colorbox({rel: $(this).attr('rel')});
});
```

This code also allows grouping.

Answer (score 4):

This post is old but this may help others:
simonthetwit solution is ok, but you'll need to click the trigger link twice. Colorbox can be called directly, so this should work:

```
$( '.colorbox' ).live('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.colorbox({open:true});
        //inline example
        //$.colorbox({inline:true, width:"50%", href:"#inline_content"});
});
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Here was the solution I found to avoid the needing of clicking twice the link to fire the event:

```
$(document.body).delegate('.<my-class>', 'click', function(e) {  
    e.preventDefault();  
    $('.<my-class>').colorbox({<my-code>})  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem as @sunburst with having to click the trigger link twice. Used the same code, but `.delegate()` instead of `.live()`. Solved everything and cleaned up my jQuery nicely!

Nice explanation here: http://www.alfajango.com/blog/the-difference-between-jquerys-bind-live-and-delegate/