# Add jQuery colorbox plugin to a dynamically created element, extra problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, colorbox

I saw the answer of a question: [Add jQuery colorbox plugin to a dynamically created element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443490/add-jquery-colorbox-plugin-to-a-dynamically-created-element)

Solve part of the problem, works fine, but when I click for second time, it doesn't work.
When I try to click for second time an error displays: **$.fn.colorbox is not a function**.
How can i correct that error and avoid a double click to bind colorbox.

I don't speak english, i did my best to write this words, i hope you can read me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.colorbox').die().live('click', function() {
  $.colorbox({href:$(this).attr('href'), open:true});
  return false;
}
```

That should help you put a ".die()" before the ".live("

Comment: I tryed, but it does the same: $.fn.colorbox is not a function

Comment: that case it means that javascript cannot find the function. there are two reasons for this. `A`: if the colorbox is not loaded. `B`: Because you have made a scripting error and the function seems like it doesn't exist. `so` check that you have the colorbox as a function or debug ur script.

Comment: ah nice this works except it does not work with grouped elements.

Comment: you can try die('click'). which will kill only the on click functions for that element and ignore the rest.

Comment: I tried this code and it doesn't seem to unbind the events correctly. It does achieve the goal of calling colorbox on dynamic elements but I'm finding that it attaches the click handler every time the element is clicked (leading to +1 callbacks each time). I'll post a fix when I figure it out...