# Triggering a second click after the first click event event has finished?

Tags: jquery, plugins

This is a 'hack' that enables the [colorbox jQuery plugin](http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) to work with the jQuery `live` and the `rel` attribute (so you can group images int he lightbox):

```
 $('a[rel="group1"]').live('click', function(){ 
    $('a[rel="group1"]:not(.cboxElement)').colorbox(); 
    return false; 
  }).colorbox();
```

Now, the problem is that the lightbox only appears the second time you click on it.

So I thought I could automatically trigger the second click (after the events in the first one are finished).

Any suggestions to accomplish this?

**EDIT:**

I searched on Google about how to use the jQuery `live` and colorbox and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443490/add-jquery-colorbox-plugin-to-a-dynamically-created-element).

Then I realized that it doesn't work with groups of images.

Then I found this [hack](http://groups.google.com/group/colorbox/browse_thread/thread/da42e12cc80b9c7b) but it requires a second click.

Dynamically generated HTML:

```
$('#menu-item-27052').append("<a rel='group1' href='images/orion_beer.jpg'>test</a>")
$('#menu-item-27052').append("<a rel='group1' href='images/dish2.jpg'>test 2</a>")
```

Comment: what is making you resort to a hack? you should address that issue first. in terms of forcing a click..you can just do $('a[rel="group1"]').click();

Comment: I feel as though there is a much simpler/better way to be handling this. You might want to post another question where you show more of your html/js model.

Comment: @Nitin Kumar OK, please see my EDIT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can call `$(this).trigger('click', false)`, the `false` passes an argument to the event handler that you can check the existence of so you don't run an infinite loop:

```
$('a[rel="group1"]').live('click', function(event, reTrigger){
    $('a[rel="group1"]:not(.cboxElement)').colorbox();
    if (typeof(reTrigger) == 'undefined' || reTrigger == false) {
        $(this).trigger('click', false);
    }
    return false; 
}).colorbox();
```

I'm not sure what you're accomplishing with this but it seems like a strange work-around. Perhaps your code can call the colorbox plugin in a different way.

Maybe you should run `.colorbox()` on the elements as they are added to the DOM so when they are clicked it's already setup and ready to go.

### Update

```
$('#menu-item-27052').append("<a rel='group1' href='images/orion_beer.jpg'>test</a>");
$('#menu-item-27052').append("<a rel='group1' href='images/dish2.jpg'>test 2</a>");
$('.group1').colorbox();
```

Just call the `.colorbox()` function on the elements after they have been added to the DOM. If the Colorbox plugin has a "destroy" method to remove instances, then you should call that first:

```
$('#menu-item-27052').append("<a rel='group1' href='images/orion_beer.jpg'>test</a>");
$('#menu-item-27052').append("<a rel='group1' href='images/dish2.jpg'>test 2</a>");
$('.group1').colorbox.remove().colorbox();
```

On a side-note you should concoct a string and append all the DOM elements at once, if you use `.append()` a bunch it will slow down the execution of the code:

```
$('#menu-item-27052').append("<a rel='group1' href='images/orion_beer.jpg'>test</a><a rel='group1' href='images/dish2.jpg'>test 2</a>");
$('.group1').colorbox.remove().colorbox();
```

Comment: please see my EDIT that's how I reached that strange workaround.

Comment: Damn just wasted 2 hours of my life with this hack. The solution was much simpler. Thanks!