# colorbox content not loading from modified playlist output generated by simpletube jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, youtube, thumbnails, colorbox, playlist

i've attached dynamically generated links to thumbnails generated by the [simpletube jquery plugin](http://hereswhatidid.com/simpletube/) by replacing:

```
for (var i=0; i<intResultsLength; i++) {
if (options['displaytype'] === 'user') {
_objThumbsHolder.append('<div><img src="' + entries[i].thumbnail.sqDefault + '" class="' + entries[i].id + '" /><br /><span class="thumbdescription">'+entries[i].title+'</span></div>');
if (options['defaultvideo'] === entries[i].id) {
intDefault = i;
}
```

with:

```
for (var i=0; i<intResultsLength; i++) {
if (options['displaytype'] === 'user') {
_objThumbsHolder.append('<div id="my_id_name"><a class="youtube" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + entries[i].id + '?rel=0&autohide=1&showinfo=0&autoplay=0&iv_load_policy=3&wmode=transparent"><img src="' + entries[i].thumbnail.hqDefault + '" class="' + entries[i].id + '" /></a><br /><span class="thumbdescription">'+entries[i].title+'</span></div>');
if (options['defaultvideo'] === entries[i].id) {
intDefault = i;
}
```

on line 64 in jquery.simpletube.js.  i achieved this by taking the `+ entries[i].id +`variable which was used to apply a class to the thumbnail (and is the videos id) and used it again for the link.

i've also made the following tweaks

- named the div wrapping the thumbnail (for styling)
- wrapped a href link around the thumbnail (so it becomes a link)
- added some code to the href link so that it has the same properties as other links on the site which pop open in colorbox.  (so that it opens in a pop up)
- removed the actual video player instance (as that is not needed because the video is playing in the pop up colorbox).

so everything is working except i get this error in colorbox when clicking on the link:

'This content failed to load.'

i've checked the element in firebug and the only difference between the links' code is that the thumbnail links have a class of 'youtube', whereas the other links have automatically had 'cboxElement' appended to their class, making their class 'youtube cboxElement'.  when i manually change the thumbnail link class to 'youtube cboxElement' this is when colorbox pops up but then the 'failed to load' message shows.

i have triple checked my links are accurate and that the link code of the thumbnail links and the other site links are the same.

so my only ideas are that...well actually i don't have any - i thought maybe simpletube was removing a default action of the link, but that can't be the case because colorbox is popping up, it is just failing to load the content.

firebug error console shows no errors or warnings.

thank you.

ps the colorbox call i am using is:

```
$(".youtube").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"800px"});
```

**update**

still working on this, i am wondering if it has something to do with colorbox not binding to elements that have been dynamically generated.

in that vein, i have come across:

[Add jQuery colorbox plugin to a dynamically created element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443490/add-jquery-colorbox-plugin-to-a-dynamically-created-element)

and have added this before the closing body tag of my document (it doesn't work in the head area):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$( '.new_youtube' ).live('click',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$.colorbox({open:true});
});
});
</script>
```

and so the link now looks like this in firebug:

```
<a class="new_youtube" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/xx-xxxxxxxx?rel=0&autohide=1&showinfo=0&autoplay=0&iv_load_policy=3&wmode=transparent">
```

colorbox launches, but then gets stuck on the loading animated gif.

Answer (score 0):

i added this to the bottom of the existing colorbox code block in the head:

```
$( '.new_youtube' ).live('click',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$(this).colorbox({open:true, iframe:true, width:"800px", height: "493px", onClosed:function(){
$(".new_youtube").removeClass('cboxElement');
}
});
});
```

note: i had to unbind the events otherwise when clicking on the thumbnail again, two instances of the video player were in the colorbox pop up.  (thanks to [this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/colorbox/-73QlB2Wnbc/XU6vgTLBNUUJ) for how to do that).

and the simpletube link contructor ended up being:

```
<div id="my_id_name"><a class="new_youtube" href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + entries[i].id + '?rel=0&autohide=1&showinfo=0&autoplay=0&iv_load_policy=3&wmode=transparent"><img src="' + entries[i].thumbnail.hqDefault + '" class="' + entries[i].id + '" /></a><br /><span class="thumbdescription">'+entries[i].title+'</span></div>
```